# I am getting an error when I tried to cross compile Libcork on windows using Cygwin (similar version of ipsets present in windows)

Tags: linux, windows, networking, ip, cross-compiling

I tried to install a library called Libcork in windows using Cygwin. It is just like IP_SETS which is present in Linux(IP_SETS). I am getting an error while tried to cmake

In file included from

```
/cygdrive/c/users/dines/downloads/ipset/libcork/include/libcork/core/hash.h:16,
                 from /cygdrive/c/users/dines/downloads/ipset/libcork/include/libcork/core/callbacks.h:14,
                 from /cygdrive/c/users/dines/downloads/ipset/libcork/include/libcork/core/allocator.h:18,
                 from /cygdrive/c/users/dines/downloads/ipset/libcork/include/libcork/core.h:15,
                 from /cygdrive/c/users/dines/downloads/ipset/libcork/src/libcork/cli/commands.c:15:
/cygdrive/c/users/dines/downloads/ipset/libcork/include/libcork/core/byte-order.h:45:2: error: #error "Unknown endianness"
   45 | #error "Unknown endianness"
      |  ^~~~~
/cygdrive/c/users/dines/downloads/ipset/libcork/include/libcork/core/hash.h: In function ‘cork_stable_hash_buffer’:
/cygdrive/c/users/dines/downloads/ipset/libcork/include/libcork/core/byte-order.h:175:44: error: implicit declaration of function ‘CORK_UINT32_LITTLE_TO_HOST’; did you mean ‘CORK_UINT32_HOST_TO_BIG’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  175 | #define CORK_UINT32_HOST_TO_LITTLE(__u32)  CORK_UINT32_LITTLE_TO_HOST(__u32)
      |                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/cygdrive/c/users/dines/downloads/ipset/libcork/include/libcork/core/hash.h:107:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘CORK_UINT32_HOST_TO_LITTLE’
  107 |         uint32_t  k1 = CORK_UINT32_HOST_TO_LITTLE(cork_getblock32((const uint32_t *) curr, 0));
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/libcork-shared.dir/build.make:83: src/CMakeFiles/libcork-shared.dir/libcork/cli/commands.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:353: src/CMakeFiles/libcork-shared.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:161: all] Error 2
```

Does any body tried this before. I anyone did can I get some info about how to overcome this issue.

Comment: I didn't meant to answer with the WSL just a comment, If you compile on WSL it will compile for linux as far as I know at least with golang, but you can specify with is you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you using windows 10 maybe try using WSL instead of Cygwin, here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Comment: I am newbie here don;t mind if I am wrong. By using the WSL the end product will be in LinuxI think.Is it? I am the end product to be windows executable.